# ¿A que se refiere que los atributos de una clase estén encapsulados?

Tags: java, poo

Tengo una tarea en la cual especifica que debo crear una clase con ciertos atributos encapsulados, pero no sé qué es que estén encapsulados ni como definir el encapsulamiento dentro del programa, ¿Me ayudan?

Utilizo el IDE de NetBeans, para Java.

Comment: [Espero te ayude](https://guru99.es/java-oops-encapsulation/) a entender el concepto ,lo siguiente es aplicarlo a los objetos de tu clase y/o métodos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El encapsulamiento consiste en ocultar información al exterior, al gusto o necesidades del programador.
Por ejemplo:

```
public class Ejemplo{

     private int numero = 0;
     public int otroNumero = 1;

     public int getNumero(){
          return this.numero;
     }

}
```

Si creamos un objeto de la clase Ejemplo pasará lo siguiente:

```
public class OtroEjemplo{

     public static void main(){
          Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();
          System.out.println(ejemplo.otroNumero); //Devuelve 1
          System.out.println(ejemplo.getNumero()); //Devuelve 0
          //System.out.println(ejemplo.numero); Este daría error
     }
}
```

Esto está muy relacionado con la visibilidad de los atributos.

Te recomiendo que repases estos conceptos.

¡Si necesitas mas ayuda solo pídemela!